# Having issues in functions inside function in javascript (eventlistener)

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Got those Event Listeners out of the functions. Works ok except when 2 sounds in a row are the same, the second sound isn't said, sometimes. No idea where this comes from. Other issue : if the game is reset when unfinished then I get double sounds. I don't know where to remove the EventListeners if they are the problem.  Isn't it troublesome to have the same event (click on cells) with 2 different targets ?

Here's the code :

```js
//Pour placer les images dans le tableau (sinon enlever cette partie pour avoir les images en ligne avec fonction shuffle dans un flex)

let cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let nbreCards = cards.length;
cell1.appendChild(card1);
cell2.appendChild(card2);
cell3.appendChild(card3);
cell4.appendChild(card4);
cell5.appendChild(card5);
cell6.appendChild(card6);

//Pour mélanger les images dans le tableau.
function shuffle() {
  let cardVar = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6];

  for (let cardPosition = cardVar.length - 1; cardPosition >= 1; cardPosition--) {
    let numrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cardPosition + 1));
    let sauve = cardVar[cardPosition];
    cardVar[cardPosition] = cardVar[numrandom];
    cardVar[numrandom] = sauve;
  }
  //Mélange aléatoire des cartes du tableau
  cell1.appendChild(cardVar[0]);
  cell2.appendChild(cardVar[1]);
  cell3.appendChild(cardVar[2]);
  cell4.appendChild(cardVar[3]);
  cell5.appendChild(cardVar[4]);
  cell6.appendChild(cardVar[5]);
}


//Pour jouerSon aléatoire  sans doublon ... à finir...

//Récupérer array des sons et nombre de sons :



function sonsAleatoires() {
  //Arrays of win and loose            
  let reussitesArray = [];
  let echecsArray = [];



  let sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  let nbreSounds = sounds.length;
  let soundsArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < nbreSounds; i++) {
    sons = sounds[i];
    let x = sons.getAttributeNode('id').value;
    soundsArray.push(x);
  }

  //Duplique deux fois la liste des sons pour en avoir une vingtaine
  let soundsArray2 = soundsArray.slice();
  let soundsArray3 = soundsArray2.slice();
  let soundsArray4 = soundsArray.concat(soundsArray2, soundsArray3);


  //Randomize sounds 
  for (let soundPosition = soundsArray4.length - 1; soundPosition >= 1; soundPosition--) {
    let numrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (soundPosition + 1));
    let sauve = soundsArray4[soundPosition];
    soundsArray4[soundPosition] = soundsArray4[numrandom];
    soundsArray4[numrandom] = sauve;
  }

  console.log(soundsArray4);

  let p = -1;
  let numsnd;

  son();

  function son() {
    p++;
    if (p >= soundsArray4.length) {
      return;
    } else {
      let sonAjouer = document.getElementById(soundsArray4[p]);
      let snd = sonAjouer.getAttributeNode('id').value;
      numsnd = Number(snd.charAt(3));
      sonAjouer.play();
    } //fin du if             
  } //fin de son

  let cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  let nbreCells = cells.length;
  for (var y = 0; y < nbreCells; y++) {
    cells[y].addEventListener('click', donnerResultat);
  }

  function donnerResultat() {
    let idCell = "";
    let contenuCell = "";
    let numImage = 0;
    idCell = (this.id);
    contenuCell = document.getElementById(idCell).lastElementChild.getAttributeNode('id').value;
    numImage = Number(contenuCell.charAt(4));
    if (p >= soundsArray4.length) {
      return;
    }

    //Compares id soundn and id img cliqued  
    if (numsnd === numImage) {
      reussitesArray.push(1);


      document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "#83f500";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "";
      }, 1000);


    } else {
      echecsArray.push(contenuCell);
      document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "#f13022";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = ""
      }, 1000);
    } //fin du if 

  } //end of function donnerResultat

  //next sound 
  for (var c = 0; c < nbreCells; c++) {
    cells[c].addEventListener('click', son, false);
  }

} //end of sonsAleatoires
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffeb3b63
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #FF5722;
}

.main {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.card img {
  max-height: 12vw;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #9C27B0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons {
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vw;
}

.buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#button1 {
  display: none;
}

#button,
#button1,
#button3,
#button4 {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 10vw;
  float: right;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 65%;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #9c27b0;
  //border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 4vw bold;
  color: #FFC107;
  background-color: #d0e21b6e
}

td {
  width: 31%;
}

.cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #795548a1
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 4vw;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Listen and point to</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="newscript.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header"> Ecoute et clique </h1>
  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td id="cell1"></td>
        <td id="cell2"></td>
        <td id="cell3"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="cell4"></td>
        <td id="cell5"></td>
        <td id="cell6"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="card" id="card1"><img id="img1" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/frere_nb.png" alt="frere"></div>
    </td>
    <div class="card" id="card2"><img id="img2" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/soeur_nb.png" alt="soeur"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card3"><img id="img3" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/mere_nb.png" alt="mere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card4"><img id="img4" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/pere_nb.png" alt="pere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card5"><img id="img5" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/grandmere_nb.png" alt="gdmere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card6"><img id="img6" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/grand_pere_nb.png" alt="gdpere"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="buttons">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="image" id="button3" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/bouton-son.png" alt="bouton" onclick="sonsAleatoires()" /></li>
      <li><input type="image" id="button4" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/repeat.PNG" alt="bouton" onclick="replay()" /></li>
      <li><input type="image" id="button1" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/read.png" alt="bouton" onclick="afficher()" /></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <audio id="son1">
      <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/broth.ogg" type="audio/ogg">   
      <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/broth.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
  <audio id="son2">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/sister.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/sister.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
  <audio id="son3">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/moth.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/moth.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
  <audio id="son4">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/fath.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> 
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/fath.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
  <audio id="son5">  
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdm.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
  <audio id="son6">  
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdf.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          </audio>

  <p id="Moyenne" </p>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet does nothing. Please change the snippet so it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I updated the snippet to show the issues. It works through if you don't interrupt the process by clicking on the play button. If that happens I get multiple sounds at the same time. I don't know how to remove the EventListener here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An event listener is being added to cells on every call to `sonsAleatoires()`.

```js
function sonsAleatoires() {

  /* ... */

  function son() {
    /* code snip */        
  } //fin de son

  /* ... */

  // add click listener to each cell:

  //next sound 
  for (var c = 0; c < nbreCells; c++) {
    cells[c].addEventListener('click', son, false);
  }

}
```

This will result in multiple listeners on each cell. To prevent multiple listeners, ensure that the 'son' listeners are only added once.

Introduce a `sonListenersAdded` variable:

```js
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let nbreCards = cards.length;
cell1.appendChild(card1);
cell2.appendChild(card2);
cell3.appendChild(card3);
cell4.appendChild(card4);
cell5.appendChild(card5);
cell6.appendChild(card6);

// add this here:
let sonListenersAdded = false;
```

Then replace this:

```js
for (var c = 0; c < nbreCells; c++) {
  cells[c].addEventListener('click', son, false);
}
```

with this:

```js
if (!sonListenersAdded) {
  for (let cell of cells) {
    cell.addEventListener('click', son, false);
  }
  sonListenersAdded = true;
}
```

Working code:

```js
//Pour placer les images dans le tableau (sinon enlever cette partie pour avoir les images en ligne avec fonction shuffle dans un flex)

let cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let nbreCards = cards.length;
cell1.appendChild(card1);
cell2.appendChild(card2);
cell3.appendChild(card3);
cell4.appendChild(card4);
cell5.appendChild(card5);
cell6.appendChild(card6);
let sonListenersAdded = false;

//Pour mélanger les images dans le tableau.
function shuffle() {
  let cardVar = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6];

  for (let cardPosition = cardVar.length - 1; cardPosition >= 1; cardPosition--) {
    let numrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cardPosition + 1));
    let sauve = cardVar[cardPosition];
    cardVar[cardPosition] = cardVar[numrandom];
    cardVar[numrandom] = sauve;
  }
  //Mélange aléatoire des cartes du tableau
  cell1.appendChild(cardVar[0]);
  cell2.appendChild(cardVar[1]);
  cell3.appendChild(cardVar[2]);
  cell4.appendChild(cardVar[3]);
  cell5.appendChild(cardVar[4]);
  cell6.appendChild(cardVar[5]);
}


//Pour jouerSon aléatoire  sans doublon ... à finir...

//Récupérer array des sons et nombre de sons :



function sonsAleatoires() {
  //Arrays of win and loose
  let reussitesArray = [];
  let echecsArray = [];



  let sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  let nbreSounds = sounds.length;
  let soundsArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < nbreSounds; i++) {
    sons = sounds[i];
    let x = sons.getAttributeNode('id').value;
    soundsArray.push(x);
  }

  //Duplique deux fois la liste des sons pour en avoir une vingtaine
  let soundsArray2 = soundsArray.slice();
  let soundsArray3 = soundsArray2.slice();
  let soundsArray4 = soundsArray.concat(soundsArray2, soundsArray3);


  //Randomize sounds
  for (let soundPosition = soundsArray4.length - 1; soundPosition >= 1; soundPosition--) {
    let numrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (soundPosition + 1));
    let sauve = soundsArray4[soundPosition];
    soundsArray4[soundPosition] = soundsArray4[numrandom];
    soundsArray4[numrandom] = sauve;
  }

  // console.log(soundsArray4);

  let p = -1;
  let numsnd;

  son();

  function son(evt) {

    // console.log('son evt;', evt);

    p++;
    if (p >= soundsArray4.length) {
      return;
    } else {
      let sonAjouer = document.getElementById(soundsArray4[p]);
      let snd = sonAjouer.getAttributeNode('id').value;
      numsnd = Number(snd.charAt(3));
      console.log('son playing sound snd:', snd);
      sonAjouer.play();
    } //fin du if
  } //fin de son

  let cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  let nbreCells = cells.length;
  for (var y = 0; y < nbreCells; y++) {
    cells[y].addEventListener('click', donnerResultat);
  }

  function donnerResultat() {
    let idCell = "";
    let contenuCell = "";
    let numImage = 0;
    idCell = (this.id);
    contenuCell = document.getElementById(idCell).lastElementChild.getAttributeNode('id').value;
    numImage = Number(contenuCell.charAt(4));
    if (p >= soundsArray4.length) {
      return;
    }

    //Compares id soundn and id img cliqued
    if (numsnd === numImage) {
      reussitesArray.push(1);


      document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "#83f500";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "";
      }, 1000);


    } else {
      echecsArray.push(contenuCell);
      document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = "#f13022";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(idCell).style.backgroundColor = ""
      }, 1000);
    } //fin du if

  } //end of function donnerResultat

  //next sound
  if (!sonListenersAdded) {
    // console.log('donnerResultat adding event listeners');
    for (let cell of cells) {
      cell.addEventListener('click', son, false);
    }
    sonListenersAdded = true;
  }

} //end of sonsAleatoires
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffeb3b63
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #FF5722;
}

.main {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.card img {
  max-height: 12vw;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #9C27B0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons {
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vw;
}

.buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#button1 {
  display: none;
}

#button,
#button1,
#button3,
#button4 {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 10vw;
  float: right;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 65%;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #9c27b0;
  //border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 4vw bold;
  color: #FFC107;
  background-color: #d0e21b6e
}

td {
  width: 31%;
}

.cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #795548a1
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 4vw;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="header"> Ecoute et clique </h1>
  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td id="cell1"></td>
        <td id="cell2"></td>
        <td id="cell3"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="cell4"></td>
        <td id="cell5"></td>
        <td id="cell6"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="card" id="card1"><img id="img1" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/frere_nb.png" alt="frere"></div>
    </td>
    <div class="card" id="card2"><img id="img2" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/soeur_nb.png" alt="soeur"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card3"><img id="img3" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/mere_nb.png" alt="mere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card4"><img id="img4" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/pere_nb.png" alt="pere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card5"><img id="img5" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/grandmere_nb.png" alt="gdmere"></div>
    <div class="card" id="card6"><img id="img6" src="http://lve64.free.fr/sequences/famille_2016/images_famille_reduites/grand_pere_nb.png" alt="gdpere"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="buttons">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="image" id="button3" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/bouton-son.png" alt="bouton" onclick="sonsAleatoires()" /></li>
      <li><input type="image" id="button4" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/repeat.PNG" alt="bouton" onclick="replay()" /></li>
      <li><input type="image" id="button1" src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/buttons/read.png" alt="bouton" onclick="afficher()" /></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <audio id="son1">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/broth.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/broth.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
  <audio id="son2">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/sister.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/sister.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
  <audio id="son3">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/moth.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/moth.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
  <audio id="son4">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/fath.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/fath.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
  <audio id="son5">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdm.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
  <audio id="son6">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://lve64.free.fr/projets_jeu_navigateur/projet_cartes_lve2/famille_mots/gdf.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

  <p id="Moyenne">Moyenne</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried doing that and removing the other eventlistener above. It doesn't work : when I click on the restart button I get 2 sounds each time. Can it be because I have two different Evenet listeners on the same object (cells) ? One to start the donnerResultat function and one to start the son function ,

Comment: Looking at the console it seems that on clicking on the start button a new soundsArray4 is created but the son function plays both old and new version at the same time. How can I work this out ?

Comment: @user13635826 The problem is that the removeEventListener call isn't removing the 'son' listener. The fix is to ensure the the 'son' listeners are created only once. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The sound issue is fixed. But now if you click on the restart button during a test, the image clicked doesn't match the sound played. With the console log of numsnd I get 2 values and then 3 if I click the restart button again. I tried using your fix for the other EventListener but then there's no looping back to next sound.

Comment: @user13635826 "the image clicked doesn't match the sound played" Of course not. There is no association between images and sounds. The sound played changes every time the function `son()` is called ( p++; ... sonAjouer = document.getElementById(soundsArray4[p]; ), until the sounds array is exhausted. If you want a specific sound to be associated with a specific image, you need to write the code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from the provided code, but is it possible that you keep adding EventListeners each time you play a sound without removing them?

Maybe you can either remove them after playing a sound or only add them once (somewhere outside the son() function).

Comment: Thanks! I updated the snippet with the new code. But I can't get it to work correctly if one doesn't finish the complete row of questions. If you click on the green button during the process you get two or more sounds at the same time. I don't understand how to remove the EventListeners here.